# inside the loop i want to input (order is placed) check float(btc_price["price"])>short_ma to be true before continue the loop How to do this

Tags: python, loops, bots, trading, python-binance

```
   elif float(btc_price["price"]) >= buy1 * percentsell and buy1 !=0:

        print("sell1")
        order = client.order_market_sell(symbol="BTCUSDT", side='SELL', type='MARKET', quoteOrderQty=ordergroote)
```

"I would like to check if float(btc_price["price"])<short_ma = true
When = true then continue loop"

## i have no clue what to do

Comment: don't know what you trying to do explain your question more and be brief when asking questions..

Comment: i have a loop that buys and sell orders if this loop is called i would like to check  float(btc_price["price"])<short_ma and when this is true then continue with the loop again

Comment: add a for loop and create a if statement to check float(btc_price["price"])<short_ma and if it is true just put continue under if statement